# How do I get data from multiple table in PHP SQL?

Tags: php, sql, select, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I'm working on a school management project by using bootstrap, PHP & mysql. I just started coding with PHP so I'm not much familiar with it.

What I need that I want to select all data from table **student_info** and select only image_name from table **profile_img** through student_id like below in snapshot:

[image: Student Dashboard]

---

I used following **SELECT** SQL query to get records from above table and included the profile image also in below code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-view">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Scholar Number</th>
<th>Photo</th>
<th>Student Name</th>
<th>Class</th>
<th>Fee Status</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student_info ORDER BY 
student_roll_number LIMIT 500"); //Retrive data from table student_info
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM profile_img WHERE student_id = '$id' ORDER BY 
student_id DESC LIMIT 1"; //Retrive data from table profile_img 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){      
$id = $row["student_id"];
$rollnumber = $row["student_roll_number"];    
$fname = $row["student_fname"];
$lname = $row["student_lname"];
$class = $row["student_class"];
$image-name = $row["image_name"]; //Retrive data from table two
echo '
<tr>
<td> '.$id.'</td>
<td> '.$rollnumber.'</td>
<td class="text-center">
<img src="upload/profile_pic/'.$image-name.'.jpg" 
style="width:40px;height:30px;"></td>
<td> '.$fname.' '.$lname.'</td>
<td><i class="icon-group"></i> '.$class.'</td>
<td><center>Pending</center></td>
</tr>'
;}
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to select all info from **student_info** table and want to select only image name from table **profile_img** table and showing in one single table like below screenshot.

[image: Student Dashboard]

Anyone can help me for this?
Here are the both table screenshot:

> table **student_info**

[image]

> table **profile_img**

[image]

When I used following code I got error following error:

```
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT student_info.scholar_number, 
        student_info.student_name, 
        student_info.class, 
        student_info.fee_status, 
        profile_img.image_name
        FROM        student_info
        INNER JOIN profile_img 
        ON          profile_img.student_id = student_info.student_id;");
```

[image]

Comment: INNER JOIN ~ that's the word you are looking for. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see what your schema is, but as ArtisticPhoenix mentions you want to use INNER JOIN to join the two tables on the common field, e.g.

```
SELECT      student_info.scholar_number, 
            student_info.student_name, 
            student_info.class, 
            student_info.fee_status, 
            profile_img.image_name
FROM        student_info
INNER JOIN profile_img 
ON          profile_img.student_id = student_info.student_id;
```